# Delete key/value pair with jq when key is a known string

Tags: bash, jq

I'm trying to delete one specific key/value pair from a json file.

My json file is, for this example, `params.json`

```
[ 
 {
    "ParameterKey": "RTSMMinSize",
    "ParameterValue": "1"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "RTSMReplicateDB",
    "ParameterValue": "false"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "RTSMSnapshotID",
    "ParameterValue": "snapID"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "RTSMEMAIL",
    "ParameterValue": ""
  }
]
```

I want to remove the `RTSMSnapshotID` key value pair entirely as part of my bash script. The file should look like this after:

```
[ 
 {
    "ParameterKey": "RTSMMinSize",
    "ParameterValue": "1"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "RTSMReplicateDB",
    "ParameterValue": "false"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "RTSMEMAIL",
    "ParameterValue": ""
  }
]
```

I thought this would be something as simple as

```
jq 'del(.RTSMSnapshotID)' params.json
```

but I'm getting

```
jq: error (at <filename>): Cannot index array with string "RTSMSnapshotID"
```

Clearly I don't understand how delete works. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`del(.foo)` expects there to be a top-level dictionary with a key named `foo`. That's not the case here; instead, you have a top-level list with `ParameterKey` having a series of values, with only one of which you want to remove the entire pair.

```
jq '[ .[] | select(.ParameterKey != "RTSMSnapshotID") ]'
```

...or...

```
jq 'map(select(.ParameterKey != "RTSMSnapshotID"))'
```

Comment: I never would have considered just selecting everything else, rather than deleting that specifically. What an interesting way of looking at things. Thanks for the lesson!